# Not recognising string data type in c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, header

I am learning C++ programming in Visual C++ 2008, express edition. My  program is not identifying the `std::string` data type. I have included the `<string>` library.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "TestClass.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    double area;
    string name;

public:
    Rectangle()
    {
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
    }

    int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this->width = width;
    }

    void setHeight(int height)
    {
        this->height= height;
    }

    void setArea( )
    {
        area = width * height;
    }

    double getArea( )
    {
        return area;
    }

    Rectangle (const Rectangle & x)
    {
        this->area = x.area;
    }

    void friendtestfunction(Rectangle2 s)
    {
        cout << "" << s.name;
    }
};

int Rectangle2::stat_var = 5;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Rectangle rect;
    rect.setWidth(10);
    rect.setHeight(20);
    rect.setArea( );

    cout<< "height is equal to :" << rect.getHeight() << endl;
    cout<< "width is equal to :" << rect.getWidth() << endl;
    cout << "area is equal to :" << rect.getArea() << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I declared a private variable of type string in class Rectangle it showed the following error:

```
1>c:\users\subith.p\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\test\test\testclass.h(10) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'

1>c:\users\subith.p\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\test\test\testclass.h(10) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: lose the stdafx.h.   That caches previous runs and if you change things and it doesn't get cleared, you won't see the changes when you recompile later.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the compiler starts at the top of your source file and goes down until it gets to the bottom and it stops.  So if it hasn't seen something yet (like a #include <string>), it doesn't know about it when you try to use it.   It doesn't "glance" at the whole file to figure out what's going on and then go back and compile the code.  It's called a "single pass compiler" because it just goes over the code once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `#include <string>` to your header file `testclass.h`.

Comment: what do you think that will change?

Comment: oops, you're right.   without line numbers in the source listing, it was less obvious exactly which std::string was being referred to.  I admit I didn't count.

Answer (score 3):

This error:

1>c:\users\subith.p\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\test\test\testclass.h(10) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'

indicates that the problem is in `testclass.h` header file, which you have not shown us.

The most probable reason is that your `TestClass.h` does not see includes from `<string>`, you should reorganize your includes, move `#include <string>` above `#include "TestClass.h"`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TestClass.h"
```

---

or as a more recomended and common aproach add `#include <string>` to your `testclass.h`.

Comment: you're right in what the problem is, but your solution is brittle.  He should include <string> in both and not rely on one to include it before the other.  "Include what you use"  http://include-what-you-use.org/

Comment: I'm guessing, based on the lack of origanization presented, that no such goal exists.   Presenting the most robust and reliable solutions to new users is usually the best approach, imho.

Comment: @xaxxon ok, added you suggestion

Comment: actually I was once working on  project where all includes were supposed to be put in implementation files, and that was a real headache.

Comment: how do you make a class that has a string in it?   Does everything have to be a pointer/ref and all classes pre-declared?

Comment: headers are used as includes so if before each include you add all required headers (among others <string>) then you are not limited to pointer/ref in your class. This was supposed to speed up compile times by limiting number of unnecessary includes.

Comment: I don't get what "add all required headers" means other than to #include them.

Comment: By  "add all required headers" I meant all the headers used in TestClass.h